# Using the AWS CDK to Create an Alarm on a Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an alarm using CDK to check the free space on my DB. Without specifying the Database name I can create the alarm. However, it doesnt really do anything since there is no DB to monitor. Does anyone know how I can specify this name?  Here is what I have tried using the dimensions:

```
 new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'FreeStorageSpace', {
   metric: new cloudwatch.Metric({
      "metricName": "FreeStorageSpace",
      "namespace": "AWS/RDS",
      "period": Duration.minutes(1),
      "unit": cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
      "statistic": cloudwatch.statistics.SUM,
      "dimensions": {
          "Name": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
          "Value": "rdsalarm-development"
       },
   }),
   threshold: 90,
   evaluationPeriods: 1,

 })
```

When I try to build this I get:
Error:Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for "CfnAlarmProps"

dimensions: element 0: supplied properties not correct for "DimensionsProperty"

value: {"Name":"DBInstanceIdentifier", "Value":"rdsalarm-development"} should be a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You syntax is not correct. `dimensions` should use the dimension name as the key. The way you wrote it would make it impossible to specify multiple dimensions.

```ts
 new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'FreeStorageSpace', {
   metric: new cloudwatch.Metric({
      metricName: "FreeStorageSpace",
      namespace: "AWS/RDS",
      period: Duration.minutes(1),
      unit: cloudwatch.Unit.COUNT,
      statistic: cloudwatch.statistics.SUM,
      dimensions: {
        DBInstanceIdentifier: "rdsalarm-development"
      },
   }),
   threshold: 90,
   evaluationPeriods: 1,

 })
```

The CDK way would be to use the [helper methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseInstance.html#metricwbrfreewbrstoragewbrspaceprops) available on the `rds` L2 constructs:

```ts
 const myDbInstance: DatabaseInstance;
 new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'FreeStorageSpace', {
   metric: myDbInstance.metricFreeStorageSpace(),
   threshold: 90,
   evaluationPeriods: 1,
 });
```

Another option:

```ts
myDbInstance.metricFreeStorageSpace().createAlarm(this, 'FreeStorageSpace',
    {
        threshold: 90,
        evaluationPeriods: 1,
    }
);
```

Comment: Worked great... thanks!  I had gotten my syntax off of some other answers I found online... maybe those didnt even work!